# How can i schedule notifications in flutter framework

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows, flutter-notification

I have a flutter app for windows desktop app ,I want to schedule notification for student exit date ,
I mean I want the app Give to user notification before exit date due ,I used flutter local notifications: ^14.0.0+1 package and test it on IOS and android it is working but the package documentation not support windows platform , any way I want a way to schedule notification in future that flutter support it,